# Use pyparsing to parse expression starting with parenthesis

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to develop a grammar which can parse expression starting with parenthesis and ending parenthesis. There can be any combination of characters inside the parenthesis. I've written the following code, following the `Hello World` program from `pyparsing`.

```
from pyparsing import *

select = Literal("select")

predicate = "(" + Word(printables) + ")"

selection = select + predicate

print (selection.parseString("select (a)"))
```

But this throws error. I think it may be because `printables` also consist of `(` and `)` and it's somehow conflicting with the specified `(` and `)`.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use alphas instead of printables.

```
from pyparsing import *

select = Literal("select")
predicate = "(" + Word(alphas) + ")"
selection = select + predicate
print (selection.parseString("select (a)"))
```

If using { } as the nested characters

```
from pyparsing import *

expr = Combine(Suppress('select ') + nestedExpr('{', '}'))
value = "select {a(b(c\somethinsdfsdf@#!@$@#@$@#))}"
print( expr.parseString( value ) )

output: [['a(b(c\\somethinsdfsdf@#!@$@#@$@#))']]
```

The problem with ( ) is they are used as the default quoting characters.

Comment: Good advice - it would help the poster to be as specific as they can about just what to expect in various parts of the incoming string.  What you've written here will parse the given input, and avoids the problem of accidentally including the closing ')' as part of the contents of the parenthesized string.

Comment: Yes. If you could have number consider 'alphanums'

Comment: The question says there can be "any combination of characters" between the parentheses. I would interpret that to include more parentheses, not just letters or numbers. I see the question as asking for the PyParsing analog to the regular expression `select\s*\(.+\)`.

Comment: @Rob is right. There can be any character inside the parenthesis like `*,(,)`. So I can't use alphas or alphanums.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire I'd like to separate out the outer level parenthesis from anything inside it. The stuff inside can be outputted as it is. Something like `["(", "a", ")"]` for the given example.

Comment: is it possible to use { } as your wrappers? e.g., select { a(b) }

Comment: `printables` also contains `{` and `}`. So I don't think that'd help.

Comment: @JeromeAnthony - nestedExpr defaults to using ()'s as the enclosing characters, so you shouldn't have to switch to using {}'s.  Just `"select" + nestedExpr()` should be sufficient.

Comment: That removes all () s

Comment: It *does* retain the grouping levels of the ()'s however. Often in using pyparsing, I will write code that suppresses punctuation that, while necessary for unambiguous parsing, is just in the way when processing the results. For instance, when parsing the Python declaration "def func(arg1, arg2, arg3):", I would define the parser to return something like `["def", "func", ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]]` - the ()'s and commas are part of the syntax, but I don't really want to have to mess with them while processing the function declaration's elements.